# SQL Server 2008 filestream access is denied

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream

Can someone help with an `Access is denied` error message received when attempting to insert FILESTREAM data into SQL Server 2008?

I have an ASP.NET application running within an application pool configured with an application-specific user.  The web.config uses integrated security...

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyApp" 
        connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The application's Windows user belongs to a database role, `web_app`. This role has execute and select permissions. However I receive the following exception...

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
```

Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: Can you add some code snippets showing how you are streaming the content?

Comment: Connection string lacks logon credentials. How your application authenticates on database?

Comment: I would check the following: 1) SQL Server Service account have the right access to the folder where the Filestream is stored and is correctly configured. 2)The user (web app pool user) rights and privileges .

Comment: What account is SQL Server using? Check this in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. Also check what is the setting for FileStream access on Server Properties --> Advanced in the Sql Server Management Console.

Comment: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx) is the link on configuring filestream.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that SQL Server Service Account have right access to filestream folder.
2. Check that filestream folder is not readonly.