# Installed SQL Sever 2008 (x86) on Windows Server 2008 (x64) Issue

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008

My developer has installed SQL Sever 2008 (x86) on Windows Server 2008 (x64).

I now have a error "FILESTREAM enable is denied" Does anyone now if the SQL Sever 2008 (x86) on Windows Server 2008 (x64) will cause this error?

I think this is stopping us upload more data in the MSSQL, also On the website new registrations can not register directly or the Facebook API. I am sure this is correlated.

Comment: if this is a brand new server and you are using the file streaming functionality are the ports open on the windows firewall for it 

ie 139 and 445 ?  filestream requires these ports to be opened.

Comment: There are many online guides to enabling filestream, if you search on the ciorrect error message. Here's a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977452/sql-server-2008-filestream-access-is-denied x86 / x64 is unlikely to be the issue. You probably just haven't configured it properly

Comment: Its 100% x86 / x64 combination, i have no idea why the developer would have done this. I create new TCP Ports 139 and 445 just incase, however this didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

same issue has been logged in the below link and is marked resolved:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83900/sql-server-filestream-access-denied?newreg=79ffa2a55b7f4a90a3b141fe24fb527f

actually this is to be handled from your Firewall settings, you need to allow it from the firewall.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and lead to the article, however creating the new ports didn't fix the issue. The x86 / x64 combination seems to be the issues. I am in the learning curve of MSSQL, I guess my next mission is to understand it more and learn how to update x86 to x64.